# How to transpose a cell of Mx1 cells and vectors?

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x*N* cell, call it `X`, whose components `X{i}` (for `i` in {1, 2, ..., *N*}) are *either* *M*x1 cells of strings *or* *M*x1 numeric vectors.

NOTE: the fact that `X` contains *both* text cells and numeric vectors precludes using `cell2mat` here:

```
>> tmp = cell2mat(X);
Error using cell2mat (line 46)
All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.
```

My question is:

> What's MATLAB's "idiomatic" way to transpose this data into an array of *M* 1x*N* cells?

EDIT: To be clear, the data structure I want to arrive at, let's call it `Y`, is an *M*-long array of 1x*N* cells (each consisting of a mixture of numbers and strings).  E.g., if *N*=2, and if `X{1}` is an *M*x1 cell of strings, and `X{2}` is an *M*x1 vector of doubles, then the desired data structure `Y` is such that, for any 1 ≤ `i` ≤ *M*, `Y(i,:)` is a 1x2 cell whose first element is the `i`-th string in `X{1}` and whose second element is the `i`-th double in `X{2}`.  I.e. `Y(i,:)` would be the same as the 1x2 cell `Yi` defined as follows

```
xi1 = X(i, 1);
xi2 = X(i, 2);
Yi = {xi1{1} xi2{1}};
```

(Sorry for the awkwardness!  *I just can't find* a MATLAB expression for `Yi` directly in terms `X` and `i`, without having to create intermediate variables `xi1` and `xi2`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "transpose into an array of M 1xN cells"? What is the problem with handling this data in the way it is stored now? Are you asking how to access each element in the 1xN cell array?

Comment: I want to pass the data to functions that take as arguments such arrays of 1xN cells.

Comment: Converting a cell-array of Mx1 matrices to a single matrix is easy, just do `[X{:}]`. But what data structure do you expect to get in case of strings?

Comment: @EitanT See my latest EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to my knowledge there is no 'idiomatic' way of doing that i Matlab. Remember, we're talking about a complex data structure with nested cells and differing types.

I tried to cook up a solution based on cellfun. It quickly got complicated and I didn't even succeed. So instead I would recommend doing a simple double for loop and a if like this:

```
for a=1:size(X,2),
    for b=1:size(X{a},1),
        if iscell(X{a}),
            Y{a,b} = X{a}{b};
        else
            Y{a,b} = X{a}(b);
        end
    end
end
```

If `X = {{'s1';'s2'} [3; 4]}` then this solution will give `Y = {'s1' 3 ;'s2' 4}`.

As you see I have flattened the cell to one depth. To get your `1xN` vectors, do `Y{1,:}`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If each cell in X contains a vector of the same size convert it to a matrix, transpose that matrix and then convert it back to a cell array?

```
tmp = cell2mat(X);
Y = mat2cell(tmp', ...);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work; I've added a NOTE to my original post showing why.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function:

```
feval(@(y) feval(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0), cellfun(@(x) feval(@(varargin) varargin{3-varargin{1}}(), iscell(x),x,num2cell(x)),y,'un',0)), {{'1','2','3'},[4 5 6],{7,8,9}})
```

Or stored as a function name:

```
transpose_nest = @(cell_nest) feval(@(y) feval(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0), cellfun(@(x) feval(@(varargin) varargin{3-varargin{1}}(),iscell(x),x,num2cell(x)),y,'un',0)), cell_nest);

transpose_nest({{'1','2','3'},[4 5 6],{7,8,9}})

{{'1',4,7},{'2',5,8},{'3',6,9}}
```

It is based on a Matlab equivalent of Scheme's (apply map list '(("1" "2" "3") (4 5 6) (7 8 9))) that only works on sub cells:

```
feval(@(x) cellfun(@(varargin)[varargin],x{:},'un',0), {{'1','2','3'},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}})

{{'1',4,7},{'2',5,8},{'3',6,9}}
```

The extra part:

```
@(x) feval(@(varargin) varargin{3-varargin{1}}(), iscell(x), x, num2cell(x))
```

is an if statement within an anonymous function that calls num2cell if any sub element is a vector